# In MySQL, get number of pregnant women who received 3 ANC checkups

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am working on a project where it is required to find out the total number of pregnant women who have received 3 ANC(Ante-Natal Care) checkups done.

A pregnant women is said to receive 3 ANC checkups if any 3 of the 4 columns(visit1_date,visit2_date,visit3_date and visit4_date) have some value.

For this, I need to calculate the count of number of rows where any 3 of 4 columns given in the table are not null.

So, basically, what is required is to find a count of all rows where **any three of**

visit1_date, visit2_date,visit3_date,visit4_date are NOT NULL

My table has columns individually for each of the visit dates

I have tried using IFNULL, but I have no idea if this would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like (untested):

```
select *
from <table> 
where if(visit1_date,1,0)+if(visit2_date,1,0)+if(visit3_date,1,0)+if(visit4_date,1,0) >= 3;
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ans_checkups
WHERE (SELECT visit1_date AS visit
       UNION ALL
       SELECT visit2_date
       UNION ALL
       SELECT visit3_date
       UNION ALL
       SELECT visit4_date
       ORDER BY (visit IS NULL)
       LIMIT 1 
       OFFSET 2                     -- one less than 3
      ) IS NOT NULL ;
```

and this variation on Colin's query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ans_checkups
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(visit1_date)
             + COUNT(visit2_date)
             + COUNT(visit3_date)
             + COUNT(visit4_date)
      ) >= 3 ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c12707/7).